# Showing an equation has one positive root

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n\geq 2$ be an integer and $\beta > 0$. Consider the polynomial equation: $$p(x) = x^n + x^{n-1} - \beta = 0$$

Show the equation had exactly one positive root $p(\beta)$

Do I use the intermediate value theorem to show this? I am a little lost here, any suggestions is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can use IVT to show there's at least one positive root. Now if there were two positive roots a basic theorem from calculus would give a contradiction...

Comment: You could use Descartes' rule of signs to show this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that $p'(x)=nx^{n-1}+(n-1)x^{n-2}$ is strictly positive when $x>0$ and $n\ge 2$, hence the function $p$ is strictly increasing when $x>0$. Finally, note that $p(0)=-\beta<0$.

(Even simpler, without derivatives: both $x^n$ and $x^{n-1}$ are strictly increasing.)

Comment: Very intuitive and straightforward. Nice +1

Answer (score 0):

To show that it has at least one:

- $p(0)=-\beta<0$
- $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}p(x)=\infty$. That is, there exists some $t>0$ such that $p(t)>0$.
- Now use Bolzano's theorem.

To show that it has no more than one:

$p'(x)=nx^{n-1}+(n-1)x^{n-2}$, that does not vanish for $x>0$. Now apply Rolle's theorem.

Comment: can you explain how Rolle's theorem proves it has no more than one positive root?

Comment: @RowanS Suppose $f(a) = f(b) = 0$. Rolle's Theorem would imply $f'(c) = 0$ for some $c$, which is not possible.