# Condition number for a function

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

In the link bellow

[Showing an equation has one positive root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419044/showing-an-equation-has-one-positive-root),

It has been shown that the considered equation has exactly one positive root. What can we do in order to compute an upper and a lower bound for $Cond(p)(\beta)$ where $Cond(p)(\beta)$ is the condition number for this root?

My attempt:

I tried to use the formula bellow

$Cond(p)(a)=\frac{\vert a \rvert \lvert p(a)^{'}\rvert}{\lvert p(a) \rvert}$.

Since $p(a)$ is a root for this equation, we have
$p(a)^n + p(a)^{n-1} -\beta=0$.

I tried to use this equation to compute the condition number for $p(a)$. But I don't know I'm a right way or not.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Ok
I want to edit the question

Comment: Could it be helping to have approximations of the root ?